# Why is docker enforcing pull rate limit for a singularity build?

Tags: docker, centos7, singularity-container

I am trying to understand how the docker pull rate limit is enforced. I am doing the following:

```sh
singularity build my_img.sif Singularity
```

where the content of `Singularity` is as follows:

```
Bootstrap:docker
From:centos:7.4.1708
```

Although I haven't done a single pull in the last six hours, I am getting the following:

```sh
[root@rc-predict singularity]# singularity build my_img.sif Singularity
INFO:    Starting build...
FATAL:   While performing build: conveyor failed to get: Error reading manifest 7.4.1708 in docker.io/library/centos: toomanyrequests: 
You have reached your pull rate limit. 
You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

To make sure this limit is not coming from [centos](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos) account, I verified that I can do the following independently:

> docker pull centos:7.4.1708

Did anyone else experience this issue/know a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into a similar issue. I was logged into Docker on the command line (so could bypass rate limits), but Singularity was invoking the Docker API without authentication.

You can tell Singularity to authenticate with Docker by prepending environment variables to your command:

`SINGULARITY_DOCKER_USERNAME=<your username> SINGULARITY_DOCKER_PASSWORD=<your password> singularity build my_img.sif Singularity`

See [this](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html#authentication-via-environment-variables) for more detail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing your idea. However, even if I am an anonymous user, shouldn't docker give 200 pulls/six-hour as explained [here](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits)?

Comment: For anonymous users my understanding is they give 100/6hrs. Is this happening on a shared cluster? Or a CI server? I think Docker applies rate limits per IP, so that could be the issue (see [this](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/docker-hub-rate-limiting-how-to-prepare/37189), [this](https://medium.com/rockedscience/fixing-docker-hub-rate-limiting-errors-in-ci-cd-pipelines-ea3c80017acb), and [this](https://container-registry.com/posts/overcome-docker-hub-rate-limit/)). If not, I have no idea.

Comment: It's my exclusive workstation, only I use it but thank you.